# Oracle procedure with default and to_date shows error

Tags: oracle, default, to-date

I am using 11g 
I have table

```
CREATE TABLE Agency
(
AgencyID          int   not null PRIMARY KEY,
AgencyName        VARCHAR2(30) not null,
AgencyLtrCode     VARCHAR2(10) not null,
IsActive          VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT 'yes'NOT NULL,
LastListSentData  DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE ,
LetterSendDate    DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE ,
CertificationDate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE ,
CeresNo       int,
AgencyAreaID      int not null,
CONSTRAINT fk_Agency FOREIGN KEY (AgencyAreaID) REFERENCES AgencyArea(AriaID)
);
```

I use procedure to insert  new records in it

```
create or replace PROCEDURE insert_AGENCY_Procedure(
       AGENCYID IN AGENCY.AGENCYID%TYPE,
       AGENCYNAME IN AGENCY.AGENCYNAME%TYPE,
       AGENCYLTRCODE IN AGENCY.AGENCYLTRCODE%TYPE,  
       ISACTIVE IN AGENCY.ISACTIVE%TYPE DEFAULT 'yes',
       LASTLISTSENTDATA IN AGENCY.LASTLISTSENTDATA%TYPE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
       LETTERSENDDATE IN AGENCY.LETTERSENDDATE%TYPE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
       CERTIFICATIONDATE IN AGENCY.CERTIFICATIONDATE%TYPE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
       CERESNO IN AGENCY.CERESNO%TYPE,
       AGENCYAREAID IN AGENCY.AGENCYAREAID%TYPE)
IS BEGIN
  INSERT INTO AGENCY("AGENCYID", "AGENCYNAME","AGENCYLTRCODE","ISACTIVE","LASTLISTSENTDATA","LETTERSENDDATE","CERTIFICATIONDATE","CERESNO","AGENCYAREAID") 
  VALUES             (AGENCYID, AGENCYNAME,AGENCYLTRCODE,ISACTIVE,LASTLISTSENTDATA,LETTERSENDDATE,CERTIFICATIONDATE,CERESNO,AGENCYAREAID);
  COMMIT;
END;​​
```

right now it throw error "Error at line 17: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" "
line 17 had only END; on it

when I submit inserting which looks like

```
BEGIN
insert_AGENCY_Procedure(9003,'Some Other Church', 'SomOTCh','no',10-10-2011,10/10/2011,10/10/2011,17,2   );
END;
```

it throws error

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 4:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERT_AGENCY_PROCEDURE'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

or other insert like

```
BEGIN
insert_AGENCY_Procedure(9003,'Some Other Church',SomOTCh',DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,17,2   );
END;
```

it throws error

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 64:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DEFAULT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null
```

The question is what  is wrong with my procedure? I was trying to resolve this problem  but stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the `INSERT_AGENCY_PROCEDURE` procedure is defined to take 8 parameters but you are trying to pass in 9 parameters.  It appears that you are trying to pass in an `AgencyLtrCode` but the procedure does not take an `AgencyLtrCode` as a parameter.  You would either have to stop trying to pass in the `AgencyLtrCode` or you would need to modify the procedure to accept that parameter.

Second, you need to pass dates to the procedure given the declaration.  Your actual procedure call will error out because what you are passing in for the date parameters are not dates (and cannot be implicitly converted to dates).  Assuming that we eliminate the third parameter (which is what appears to be the `AgencyLtrCode` discussed above), you would want something like

```
BEGIN
  insert_AGENCY_Procedure(9003,
                          'Some Other Church', 
                          'no', 
                          to_date('10-10-2011', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 
                          to_date('10/10/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                          to_date('10/10/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'),
                          17,
                          2   );
END;
```

Third, your procedure is incorrect.  The parameters `LASTLISTSENTDATA`, `LETTERSENDDATE`, and `CERTIFICATIONDATE` are defined as dates so you should not call `to_date` on them.  If you do, you force Oracle to implicitly convert the date to a string using the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, then convert the string back to a date using the explicit format mask.  That will fail if the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is not what you expect.

Finally, declaring optional parameters in the middle of a procedure declaration is rarely correct.  If you want to use positional binding and you want the ability to omit parameters, the optional parameters need to be at the end of the parameter list.  You can define optional parameters in the middle of the parameter list and then use named binds (as `DazzaL` demonstrates) but that is seldom what you want to force future developers to use.

In your updated procedure, the declaration of the `AgencyLtrCode` parameter appears to be incorrect

```
AGENCYLTRCODE IN AGENCYLTRCODE%TYPE
```

needs to be

```
AGENCYLTRCODE IN AGENCY.AGENCYLTRCODE%TYPE
```

You are missing the name of the table.

Comment: i add missing line and right now it trow error "Error at line 17: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" " line 17  is END;​​

Comment: @AndreyIvanov - You added a missing line where?  To the procedure declaration?  What was the line that was added?  Did you modify the `INSERT` statement as well?  Can you update your question to specify the new procedure?

Comment: you can see nee create at the top

Comment: @AndreyIvanov - You seem to have edited your question while I was updating my answer with the syntax error.  If that was something that you missed in editing your question initially, that implies that you have not cut and pasted the code that you are actually using so the code in your question might not reflect the code you are actually using.  If that is the case, please make absolutely certain that you don't have a stray (or missing) character in the code you are actually running.  Cutting and pasting from a SQL*Plus session that shows the actual code you're using and the error would be good

Comment: i found error  for some reason application express add one more ; at the end of the statement and i was able to see it only  when i used object  browser. I delete  ; and right now it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing ninevalues, but the procedure is only expecting eight. From the table definition you seem to be missing`AgencyLtrCode` in the procedure.

In the first call you're passing dates as `10-10-2011` or `10/10/2011`, which will be evaluated as (different) numbers not dates. You need to at least enclose them in single quotes, but really ought to specify the date mask, as `to_date('10/10/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY')` rather than relying on implicit conversions.

In general, if you want to use the defaults, just leave those parameters out, do not pass `DEFAULT`; that isn't valid in that context. But because you have values to pass after the defaults, you need to name the parameters, i.e.

```
insert_agency_procedure(agency_id=>9003, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no DEFAULT keyword, you just omit the defaults.

in your case you have the defaults in the middle of the API though, so you'd have to use NAMED notation:

```
begin
  insert_agency_procedure(agencyid => 9003,
                          agencyname => 'Some Other Church',
                          isactive => 'SomOTCh',
                          ceresno => 17,
                          agencyareaid => 2 );
end;
/
or mixed:
begin
  insert_agency_procedure(9003, 'Some Other Church',
                          'SomOTCh',
                          ceresno => 17,
                          agencyareaid => 2 );
end;
/
```

and in the first exmaple you gave:

```
BEGIN
insert_AGENCY_Procedure(9003,'Some Other Church', 'SomOTCh','no',10-10-2011,10/10/2011,10/10/2011,17,2   );
END;
```

you cant just type dates like that. Firstly quote them. Secondly always always use a format mask.

```
BEGIN
insert_AGENCY_Procedure(9003,'Some Other Church', 'SomOTCh','no',
                        to_date('10-10-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
                        to_date('10-10-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
                        to_date('10-10-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),17,2   );
END;
```

Comment: but  the problem is column                                     IsActive in table is not null, by using your methods oracle throw error that ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("FOODBANK"."AGENCY"."AGENCYLTRCODE")that  means it is not applying default value which is 'yes'

Comment: you have no default, as you haven't got a parameter for that "AGENCYLTRCODE". you need to define it in the insert + api. if you have such a parameter with default, and don't pass it in, it would have defaulted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enclose your date string in single quotes (if you supply a date, considering you have default values for those parameters):

```
BEGIN
insert_AGENCY_Procedure(9003,'Some Other Church', 'SomOTCh','no','10-10-2011','10/10/2011','10/10/2011',17,2 );
END;
```